# using whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo to find Substring in middle of string

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating an `autoCompleteTextView` by using data from firestore.

My firestore cloud is built as follows:

[image: Names (collection) -> ID's (generated by auth.getUid()) -> UserName field]

Where for example I have 2 UserNames:

```
UserName 1 = "he is ok, ben"
UserName 2 = "ben is ok"
```

In order to autoComplete the names, I search the cloud by using:

```
db.collection( "Names" )
        .whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("UserName", s.toString() ).whereLessThanOrEqualTo( "UserName", s.toString() + "\uF7FF" ).get()
        .addOnCompleteListener( new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        String name = document.getString( "UserName" );
                        names.add( name );
                    }

                }

            }
        } );
```

Now, if for example I type `"be"`, the code above works good and finds the result for UserName 2 (`ben is ok`) but it wont find the first one since the UserName doesnt start with ben.

How can I make sure that it finds any UserName as long as "be" is a substring?

I tried also to change the data into array that will look as:

[image]

and to perform `whereArrayContains`. Again, this solution works only if I typed a whole word from the array (for example if I wrote `be` I got no result, and only if I wrote `ben` it found since ben is a full part of the array object).

Is there any way I can find a substring from either a string or an array no matter where it appears in the sentence?

Comment: Firestore does not offer substring queries, as they do not scale effectively.